# How to save to database with my custom _id?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to save data to a database with my custom `_id`, 
but I get an error: `Cast to ObjectID failed for value...`

I think that I shoyld convert my `_id` and then call the `save()` method.

Here is my code for this:

```
   var uid = decodedToken.uid;
            var body = _.pick(req.body, ['email' , 'fname', "lname", "providerID"]);
            body._id = uid;

            var userEX = new UserEX(body);
            userEX.save().then( (user) => {
                res.send(user);
            }).catch( (err) => {
                res.status(400).send(err);
            });
```

Hope you can help me with that.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom **uid** is not of type ObjectID.

By default Mongoose **_id** is of type ObjectID so they don't match.

You could specifically define **_id** in your schema to be the same type as your custom **uid**, for example:

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    // Other fields
});
```

However, it might be a better idea to leave the default **_id** as ObjectID and have a secondary **uid** field which you can use to query, etc.